# Additional level using MultiIndex.from_tuples in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tuples

In my DataFrame I need to have 3 header rows. The header lines are as an example in the attached image. I'm using python, streamlit and pandas. How do I do the levels below?
1a. line header: ColA ColB
2a. line header:  A    B     A    B
3a. line header: abc   abc   abc  abc

Comment: Can you provide a DataFrame constructor of the input and expected output? The logic is currently unclear and just using text is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `from_tuples`, but rather [`from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['colA', 'colB'],
                                   ['A', 'B'],
                                   ['a', 'b', 'c']])

df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 1, 2], columns=cols)
```

Output:

```
  colA                          colB                         
     A              B              A              B          
     a    b    c    a    b    c    a    b    c    a    b    c
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: The text in the 1st. and 2nd. header line appears repeated for each text in the 3rd header line. Is there a way for me to merge the cell?